# React Hooks - set last value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to write basic hooks to get currentScroll, lastScroll, scrollSpeed while scrolling.

```
function useDocScroll() {
  const isClient = typeof window === "object"

  function getScroll() {
    return isClient
      ? window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop
      : undefined
  }

  const [docScroll, setDocScroll] = useState(getScroll)
  const [lastScroll, setLastScroll] = useState(null)
  const [scrollSpeed, setScrollSpeed] = useState(Math.abs(docScroll - lastScroll))

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isClient) {
      return false
    }

    function handleScroll() {
      setDocScroll(getScroll())
      setLastScroll(getScroll())  // <-- why is this working?
      // setLastScroll(docScroll) // <-- why is this not working?

      setScrollSpeed(Math.abs(docScroll - lastScroll)) // <-- why is this not working?
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll)
  }, [])

  return [docScroll, lastScroll, scrollSpeed]
}
```

It seems like when I do `setLastScroll(getScroll())`, it saves the last scroll value well.

But I don't understand because when `handleScroll()` is firing, shouldn't `getScroll()` value stays the same? I don't get it why `setDocScroll(getScroll())` and `setLastScroll(getScroll())` have different value.

Also, I thought I could do `setLastScroll(docScroll)`, meaning 'set lastScroll value with current docScroll value', but it just prints '0' while docScroll value changes.

Why is this? I want to understand better.

+) And I can't get `scrollSpeed` which is calculated by `docScroll` and `lastScroll`, but I don't know how to get those values.

[image: Edit distracted-golick-c89w3]

Comment: Did you mean `const [docScroll, setDocScroll] = useState(getScroll())` instead of `const [docScroll, setDocScroll] = useState(getScroll)` ?

Comment: @MoinulHossain I actually wrote it based on this hooks: https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/

So I don't know.. should I do `useState(getScroll())` instead of `useState(getScroll)`?

Comment: ah nvm, it will work. forgot that useState takes function as well as the initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think why your code not working is because of following two reasons:

1. using `docScroll` directly after `setDocScroll` won't work because setState is asynchronous task. There is no guarantee that `docScroll` is updated before executing next statement
2. you are getting `0` because of scrolling happening inside some particular element (probably). Since `document.documentElement` points to `html` element and there is no scrolling inside it. So you receive `0`

Solution:

You don't need multiple `useState`s. Since scroll events emits too frequently, i think its good idea to use `useReducer` to reduce number of renders. It is important understand where scrolling happening whether on root level or inside some element.

For below solution i proposed:

if scroll happening on root level (html element) no need to pass element to `useDocScroll`. If scroll happening inside particular element, you need to pass element reference.

```
const initState = {
  current: 0,
  last: 0,
  speed: 0,
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "update":
      return {
        last: state.current,
        current: action.payload,
        speed: Math.abs(action.payload - state.current) || 0,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const isClient = () => typeof window === "object";
function useDocScroll(element = document.documentElement) {
  const [{ current, last, speed }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState);

  function getScroll() {
    return isClient() ? element.scrollTop : 0;
  }

  function handleScroll() {
    dispatch({ type: "update", payload: getScroll() });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isClient()) {
      return false;
    }

    element.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => element.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return [current, last, speed];
}
```

Example:

if scroll happening inside window

```
const {current, last, speed} = useDocScroll()
```

if scroll happening in particular element

```
const {current, last, speed} = useDocScroll(document.getElementById("main"))
```

Comment: This looks a very fine solution to the problem posed, but you add no description or textual help.

Comment: I didn't know about the useReducer. It really suits my needs! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It not working [due to closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!isClient) {
    return false;
  }

  function handleScroll() {
    setDocScroll(getScroll());

    // On calling handleScroll the values docScroll & lastScroll
    // are always will be of the first mount,
    // the listener "remembers" (closures) such values and never gets updated
    setLastScroll(docScroll);
    setScrollSpeed(Math.abs(docScroll - lastScroll));

    // v Gets updated on every call
    setLastScroll(getScroll());
  }

  // v Here you assigning a callback which closes upon the lexical scope of
  // docScroll and lastScroll
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, []);
```

To fix it, a possible solution can be a combination of a reference ([`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)) and functional [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

For example:

```
setScrollSpeed(lastScroll => Math.abs(getScroll() - lastScroll))
```

Not sure why `lastScrolled` needed:

```
function useDocScroll() {
  const [docScroll, setDocScroll] = useState(getScroll());
  const lastScrollRef = useRef(null);
  const [scrollSpeed, setScrollSpeed] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isClient) {
      return false;
    }

    function handleScroll() {
      const lastScroll = lastScrollRef.current;
      const curr = getScroll();
      setScrollSpeed(Math.abs(getScroll() - (lastScroll || 0)));
      setDocScroll(curr);

      // Update last
      lastScrollRef.current = curr;
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return [docScroll, lastScrollRef.current, scrollSpeed];
}
```

[image: Edit hidden-architecture-p8xbi]

Comment: then what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I changed it with your code, still `scrollSpeed` gives me NaN.

Comment: No one can't guess how you changed and what value you except without showing

Comment: I added codesandbox link to the post. Please check it.
I need `lastScroll` value to use it for other functions.

Comment: Well, again lastScroll is in closure, you need to use reference, Ill make an example, please read about closures.

Comment: Updated, I'm not sure why you need `docScroll` and `lastScroll` when it always the same value except on mount, (better use a boolean)